# New sort mode for tags: most recently edited

Tags: feature-request, tags, sorting

I would like to request the creation of a new sorting mode for tags at /tags (in addition to the existing "popular", "name", and "new"): a mode that sorts by the time of the **most recent edit to the tag's wiki and/or excerpt**. We can call this sort mode "active" (by analogy with the sorting mode for questions), or "most recently edited", or something like that.

The primary use case I envision for this is making it easier to identify cases in which plagiarism (of Wikipedia or whatnot) occurs in tag wikis. As things currently stand, people reviewing suggested edits to tag wikis will often approve plagiarizing edits (because they don't expect to have to check for plagiarism).<sup>1</sup> Once the plagiarizing edit has been approved, it becomes nigh-impossible to effectively detect the plagiarism, because there's *nothing* on the site that tells you which tags have been edited recently. You'd have to go through every single tag and check the wiki/excerpt histories for each to even know which tags have been edited.

By adding a sort mode that makes the most-recently-edited tags the most visible, we can effectively solve this problem: any user specifically searching for plagiarism could use this new sort mode and spend just a few minutes looking at recent changes to tag wikis/excerpts in order to determine where plagiarism has occurred (and fix it, of course).

I am aware that you can kludge something like this together in SEDE, but I would prefer not to have to do that.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, at least with *suggested* edits to tag wikis, you can at least try and look at /review/suggested-edits/history and Ctrl+F for "wiki". What if you're dealing with rubbish edits by trusted users (20k+)? Sure, we would like to think that they would know better, but sometimes, they don't. And tag wiki edits made by trusted users are 100% untraceable without going through each tag individually (or, again, using SEDE).

Answer (score 2):

As this feature request is approaching the 6 to 8 timeframe without any noticeable progress let's at least share the SEDE query I kludged together, so the community can better judge if this feature will be helpful in curating the tag wikis and excerpts on the SE sites.

```sql
select t.tagname
     , concat('site://'
       , 'tags/'
       , t.tagname
       , '/info'
       , '|'
       , t.tagname
       , ' / info') [Link to excerpt/wiki]
     , max(e.LastEditDate) [Last Excerpt edit date]
     , max(w.LastEditDate) [Last Wiki edit date]
     , case 
       when max(e.LastEditDate) > max(w.LastEditDate) 
       then max(e.LastEditDate) 
       else max(w.LastEditDate)
       end lastactive
from tags t
left outer join posts e on e.id = t.excerptpostid
left outer join posts w on w.id = t.wikipostid 
group by t.tagname
order by [lastactive] desc
```

When run today the result looks like this:

[image: tags that had their wiki or excerpt recently edited]

Keep in mind SEDE, with its awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial), is only update once a week, on sunday. Join [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) to say Hi and discuss this answer.